# How do I disable username annotations in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, annotations, git-blame

I'm not sure if it was an update or I enabled a setting but I am seeing my code annotated with git blame usernames inline with the code.

The git blame action says it is turned off.

When I click on the username the column with the line numbers expands and shows the timestamps.

How to I disable the usernames from appearing?

[image: Inline Username]

After Clicking

[image: After Clicking]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved it by right-clicking the line number column. There's an option in the menu to turn off code change information. I don't remember the exact menu option name because I don't know how to turn it back on to check.

Comment: Thanks, I emailed JetBrains, here's their reply: You can disable code author hints in Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints or you can right-click on the inlay hint and configure from the context menu.

Comment: Shawn I suggest you post your comment as answer and accept it. And thanks for the solution!

Comment: The option appears after right clicking the line without number besides the code author annotation and the option says "Hide `Code Vision: Code` author Inlay Hints".

Answer (score 23):

[image]

This can be solved by navigating to Preferences > Editor > Inlay Hints and then within Code vision they have an option (enabled by default for me) for Code author. Just disable this and it goes away.

Comment: toggle `Code vision -> Usages` to hide the usages count too

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, found your topic, and realized that it is possible to hide annotations by clicking username once again (your first screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking the author is tricky because it sometimes activates the blame (as in left click)

My quick solution: Shift-shift and write "inlay" - you will get the toggle. Need to go to another tab a back to get it actually disappear

Answer (score -3):

Right-click any **line number**. Then uncheck `Annotate with Git Blame`

[image: unblame - by unchecking "Annotate with Git Blame"]

Counter-intuitively, you cannot right-click the annotation itself (the part you want to disappear). You have to right-click the **line number**. Or right-click the line of **code** and the same option is buried in the Git submenu.

<sub>Credit for this answer goes to @SimonQue. But since [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73188530/673991) did not name the right-click option ("turn off code change information" is not very helpful because it is very different from "Annotate with Git Blame"), or provide a picture, or point out that the solution is counter-intuitive and so must be memorized (you can't right-click the thing you want to disappear; you have to right-click a thing next to it), I thought that editing his answer would rewrite it completely. So I wrote a new answer. This appears to displease some people, ah well.</sub>